# show a smarty variable with html content

Tags: html, smarty

I have a smarty variable with html content in it like:
`$html="<strong>Content</strong><br/>etc etc"`
. 
I try to show it html-formatted. When showing it like
`{$html}`
only plain text appears without formatting. I try like:
`{$html|unescape}`
but then the tags are shown but not applied. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try this:

```
{$html|unescape:'html'}
```

Also check manual:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl

Comment: Any idea how to do the same with smarty 2.x, where unescape doesn't exist?

Answer (score 47):

Interestingly, none of the answers here work with Smarty 3.1.21 on CS-Cart 4.3.4. So, just to add another thought in that circumstance, use the `nofilter` on the `$html` string like so:

`{$html nofilter}`

Comment: I love you, i was looking the same solution for the same problem in cs-cart 4.4.3 during fetching RSS feeds and displaying Post description.

Comment: Wow thank's al ot dude, it turns out this is the recommended filter to be used in Prestashop 1.7 !

Comment: i am finding solution of this problem for very long time, And it works...........

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
{$html|unescape: "html" nofilter}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: nofilter is help to solve my issue

Answer (score 3):

Use **`{$html|unescape: "html" nofilter}`**

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45371438/6110524) from Sim1-81 and ρяσѕρєя K.  I want to explain why the following code works.

The unescape:"html" modifier helps to keep the special characters in place. For example, "&euro;". ([Docs](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl)).

"nofilter" flag disables $escape_html, which essentially disables the variable being wrapped with htmlspecialchars() ([Docs](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl)).

Their solution helped as my case was to display a templated block of HTML passed in from a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of smarty `unescape` is not available. If this is the case, try using `escape:'htmlentitydecode'`.

```
{$html|escape:'htmlentitydecode'}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Smarty 2.x, the `unescape` method is not available, can try this instead;

```
{$html|html_entity_decode}
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try :

php function symbol:

```
function html($str) {
    $arr = array(
        "&lt;"      => "<",
        "&gt;"      => ">",
        "&quot;"    => '"',
        "&amp;"     => "&",
        "&#92;"     => chr(92),
        "&#39"      => chr(39),
        "&#039;"    => chr(39)
    );
    return nl2br(strtr($str,$arr));
}
```

In smarty template call:

```
{html({$html})}
```

Or without php function only smarty:

```
{$html|unescape:'allhtml'}
```

Notice: if in tpl have use `reset css` you can try remove it and try again.