# Smarty displays raw HTML

Tags: php, html, smarty

I am passing my HTML string to the `$content` variable and trying to display it, in the result I see raw HTML tags instead of the string markup.

`Controller`:

```
$content = "<strong>Test markup</strong>";
```

`index.tpl`:

`{$content}` - displays just raw variable content without markup: `<strong>Test markup</strong>` INSTEAD of the **Test markup**.

When I type manually the above variable content in the `index.tpl` then it works just fine so it seems to be some variable-related issue.

**What have I tried:**

`{content|nofilter}` - to be sure its not caused by any of the Smarty's variable filters.

Could someone help me to localize the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [show a smarty variable with html content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449583/show-a-smarty-variable-with-html-content)

Comment: @Sergiu Parashiv You're right. Its strange I couldnt find that before, thanks. I have flagged my question as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, it _is_ counter-intuitive. It should just work. As a side note: why _are_ you using Smarty?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Mostly because its a fast and flexible template engine + http://www.smarty.net/why_use :)

Comment: First I would check if the property `$smartyInstance->escape_html` is set to false. Have you really tried `{content|nofilter}` ? It looks syntactical wrong for me. I'm only familiar with this syntax  `{$content nofilter}`

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
{$content|unescape:'html'}
```

More details on: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl