# String from php as literal in smarty

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-modules

I am building prestashop module where in configuration page I have input filed where user is supposed to enter block of javascript code.

I get that code and save it to smarty but when I put it in smarty like

```
<script> 
    {$all_pages_tags}
</script>
```

I get it like string. How can I exit string and use this value as a block of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Smarty displays raw HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242713/smarty-displays-raw-html)

Answer (score 0):

There are special tags for escaping javascript-code in smarty.

For escaping javascript code with smarty variables inside you need to use {ldelim},{rdelim} like this:

```
<script> 
{ldelim}
    {$all_pages_tags}
{rdelim} 
</script>
```

Taken from the smarty documentation: [here](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl)